# ReferenceError: require is not defined in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, typescript

I am using react with Typescript in my project. I have initially created my app using create-react-app.
Now, I want to write some data to .json file but getting this error

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

Code:

```
 let to = { tracks:[this.Array] }
        const fs = require('fs');
        let data = JSON.stringify(to, null, 2); 
        fs.writeFileSync('./file.json', data);
```

The file in which i have written this has `.ts` extension.
I am new to react and typescript and have been but didn't find anything.

Comment: In react you use import to import files and functions, Require can be used but that would not make much sense

Comment: In react, you cannot import lib using `require` function. Please use 'import' keyword instead, e.g,, `import x from 'xxx';`

Comment: What do i  have to import in this case as i want to write to JSON file,any help??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `import` statements instead of `require`.

Comment: What do i have to import in this case as i want to write to JSON file,any help??

Answer (score 0):

In react you can use the import keyword to import functions, files.

Example: `import fs from './fs';`

This will import the default function export from the fs to let them use the functions fs.writeFileSync() etc.

Comment: Cannot find module './fs' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: Have you initialised your app with typescript support ? Try adding  .ts specifically to the filename if you've, otherwise check this out https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Comment: Yes it has typescript support.